# Is it possible to include hyperlink in app.config key value?

Tags: .net, web-config, app-config, key-value

Is it possible to include hyperlink as a part of text in app.config key value pair (email body text as value)? I want to generate email body from app.config key value.

**For example:**

```
<add key="EmailBody" value="Email body goes here with <a href="some link">click here</a> hyperlink/>
```

I know this is not valid, but is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no way to do what you're trying to do in the way you're trying to do it.  Attributes can't contain tags.  Provide more information about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The way i would do it is write your email body as shown but do not actually add the  etc. Instead, do something like the following :

```
<add key="EmailBody" value="Email body goes here with &&&www.google.com!!!click here£££>
```

Then, on the code side that is accessing / handling this key, replace &&& with :

```
<a href="
```

replace !!! with :

```
">
```

replace £££ with :

```
</a>
```

This is just an example, but gives you a little idea on how to get around the fact you cant have tags in attributes.

Hope this helps.