# web config string with a link asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, web-config

I have a key in my webconfig

```
<add key ="ForgotPasswordPageNonMemberMessage" value ="You are not a full member and you will not be able to login. Please click here to discover more about full membership."/>
```

I would like click here to take me to my link e.g., www.abeprakash.com

Is this possible?

In the code I am simply using

```
lblFailureMessage.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ForgotPasswordPageNonMemberMessage")
```

Comment: What type of control is `lblFailureMessage`?

Comment: label as i need to show some other messages based on various conditions.

Comment: I think this question is pretty similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196680/is-it-possible-to-include-hyperlink-in-app-config-key-value.  One answer suggests a string replacement technique.  Not sure if there's something more elegant.

Comment: I have seen that link, I don't think it is a elegant solution.

Comment: Why can't you just embed the hyperlink in the web.config? You'd just have to encode it.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0):

For now this is what I have done

```
<add key ="ForgotPasswordPageNonMemberMessage" value ="You are not a full member and you will not be able to login. To discover more about full membership"/>

 <asp:Label ID="ForgotPasswordPageMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="MyWebsite" runat="server"><a href="www.abeprakash.com">cilck here</a></asp:Label>
```

just simply show and hide MyWebsite based on the condition when ForgotPasswordPageMessage is shown.

Please suggest if you have any better way of doing this.